# NSExtension - Runtime warning - [NSXPCDecoder validateAllowedClass:forKey:]

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I am using a share extension and I get the following runtime warning:

Note: Even adding the share extension on a new project and running throws the same runtime warning

```
[Foundation] *** -[NSXPCDecoder validateAllowedClass:forKey:]: NSSecureCoding allowed classes list contains [NSObject class], which bypasses security by allowing any Objective-C class to be implicitly decoded. Consider reducing the scope of allowed classes during decoding by listing only the classes you expect to decode, or a more specific base class than NSObject. This will become an error in the future. Allowed class list: {(
    "'NSObject' (0x7fff862bc6e8) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib]"
)}
```

Given below is the Extension's info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Questions:

- What should I do to fix this warning?

Comment: Having same issue.  Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I'm adding the share extension on a new project and let extension's info.plist same as yours. But I don't see any runtime warning. My Xcode version is 13.1 and macOS 11.6 and runs app on iOS 15.1.1. Could you give more information you do?

Comment: Run the share scheme, then open safari and share the link using your app, that is when the runtime purple warning is shown.

Comment: @alionthego I got an official confirmation from Apple that it is a bug at their end while using share features, I have filed a bug report and have told them about the feedback ID. Hopefully it gets some time, for now you can ignore the purple warning

Comment: Thanks very much for letting me know.

Comment: @alionthego Just ensure your app works fine, if yes then you can ignore the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Conclusion:

- I got an official confirmation from Apple that it is a bug at their end while using share features
- I have filed a bug report and have told them about the feedback ID.
- I was told that I could ignore the error as long as I don't see any issues with my app.

### Note:

As new OS, Xcode has been released, it would be better to raise a bug and check with Apple DTS to confirm this

Comment: Any news? I'm also having this issue while sharing an image or video.

Comment: @Muhammadjon Better to check with Apple Technical Support (DTS), it has been a while since I last checked

Answer (score 4):

Just hit this issue on IOS16.1 and Xcode 14.

Can anyone confirm this if this is still a bug? Any way to suppress the warning?

Comment: It is better to check with DTS (raise TSI) and after they confirm that is a bug raise a feedback